# Regex: get css classes,ids and tags

Tags: php, html, css, regex

I have the pattern to get selectors of css code which are **.classes**, **#ids** and **html tags**. I used `preg_match` to sort them into an array just the name of the selector.

what happened is I get only the first selector *twice*, once with opened parentheses and again without.

This is the *`$contect`*:

`body{ color: black; } .class_class { color: #fff; font: tahoma; } #awesome_id{ }`

### and this is the results:

```
Array
(
    [0] => body{
    [1] => body
)
```

### this is the code:

```
<?php 
#Patterns
    $selectors  = "/(\.?\#?-?[_a-zA-Z]+[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*\s*)\{/";
#Sort
    preg_match($selectors, $content, $_selectors);
?>
<pre>
<?php
    print_r($_selectors);
?>
</pre>
```

what i want -according to the content- is for the result to be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => body
    [1] => .class_class
    [2] => #awesome_id
)
```

Comment: Consider using a DOM parser instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regular expression `~{(.*?)}~`

```
<?php

$str='body{ color: black; } .class_class { color: #fff; font: tahoma; } #awesome_id{ }';
$str = preg_replace("~{(.*?)}~s","", $str);
$arr = array_filter(explode(' ',$str));
print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => body
    [1] => .class_class
    [3] => #awesome_id
)
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/135776)

[image]

Comment: this wont work if there's no space between closing bracket and next selector. If you put " " as second parameter in preg_replace it should work even in this case.

Comment: @Dexa, Currently the regex is working as per the OP's requirement , If you want to modify , feel free to edit my answer. :)

Comment: Naah, I wont edit it, just thought of mentioning that small thing that could help out.

Comment: If I had break line between selectors that won't work.

Comment: @AbdullahSalma, I have added the `s` modifier , See the code . So it will match for line breaks too. `$str = preg_replace("~{(.*?)}~s","", $str);`

Comment: well that didn't work, to selectors got in one value. I had to do another `preg_replace`, pattern `/\r?\n|\r/` with ' '. And it worked. you got me have the way. thanks.